# Issue Connecting to PostgreSQL Locally: FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, docker, authentication, tags, pgcli

I'm facing an issue when trying to connect to a locally running PostgreSQL server. I've set up the server using Docker, and despite following the steps, I'm getting the error "FATAL: password authentication failed for user 'root'." Here are the details of my setup:

1. **Docker Command:**

   ```bash
   docker run -it \
     -e POSTGRES_USER="root" \
     -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \
     -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" \ 
     -v c:/Users/LENOVO/Data_engineering_zoomcamp1/
        2_docker_sql/ny_taxi_postgres_data2:
        /var/lib/postgresql/data \
     -p 5432:5432 \
     postgres:16
   ```

## **Connection attempt: **

- Tool: pgcli
- Command: pgcli -h localhost -p 5432 -U root -d ny_taxi

## **Observations**

- I've ensured that the PostgreSQL container starts successfully, and the server logs indicate that     it's ready to accept connections.
- The password I'm entering matches the one set during the container setup.

## **I used several troubleshooting**

- Checked Docker logs (docker logs hopeful_brown) for any errors.
- Verified PostgreSQL user and password.
- Attempted connection using psql with the same result.

## **Additional Information**:

- Operating System: Windows 11
- Docker Version: 24.0.6
- PostgreSQL Version: 16.1

Comment: The username and password environment variables are only used if no database exists when the container starts. If you have an existing database, you need to use a username/password that's defined in the database. Try running without the volume mapping to see if that's your problem. Without the volume, you'll get a new database with the root/root username/password.

Comment: Try it without the volume (from `-v....` to `.../var/lib/postgresql/data`) to test @HansKilian's suggestion.  "The password I'm entering matches the one set during the container setup." You mean literal `root`?

Comment: i have tried without the volume but still the issue persist, the postgresql server complains when trying to use the ny_taxi database,